# Why the subprojects of my BSP don't uncollapse in VS2008 (Windows CE7)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I am facing a strange problem...

I am working on a BSP with Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 8.1 virtual machine for a Windows Embedded Compact 7 system.
In the solution explorer window, I cannot uncollapse the 'Subprojects' category. When I click on the little '+' on the left of subprojects nothing happens. This is very frustrating since I cannot compile my subprojects independently.
I copied the same BSP to another VM and the problem remains.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

One of the subprojects used a .NET version which did not match the installed one. Being unable to open one of the projects, VS did not open the full list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a general issue.

I have here in front of me a virtual Windows 8.1 machine running VS2008 with Platform Builder 7.0, and opening the Subprojects folder in Solution Explorer is not a problem.

If your Platform Builder installation is fully up to date, I would suspect a corrupted workspace file, possibly an old workspace file that was not migrated correctly from a previous version of Platform Builder.

Try opening the `.pbxml` file and examine the `<PBProjectCollection>` element. Do you see your subprojects there (indicated with `<PBProject>`), and are the paths as expected?

You could also try and right-click the Subprojects folder in Solution Explorer and hit Add Existing Subproject.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It did not solve the problem but lead me to the solution.